# return None form django

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

i have a form fill for register but when i try to save it it involves a none object.

[image]

the problem is :

*The view pages.views.essai didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.*

here is my code :

views.py

```
  from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
  from django.template   import RequestContext
  from .models import Login

def essai(request):

if not request.method == 'POST':

 username = request.POST.get('username')
 password = request.POST.get('password')

 data = Login(username,password)
 print(data)

 return render(request,'pages/essai.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import URLPattern, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 path('essai', views.essai, name = 'essai'),  

]
```

essai.html

```
<form   action=""  method ="POST" >
{% csrf_token %}                    
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value ="Save">
</form>
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Login

admin.site.register(Login)
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

    class Login(models.Model):
    
        username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

PS : I tried with the forms but it's the same problem.

I do not understand where is the problem is it the views or the model

**Edit :**
I found the solution,the problem consists in the space of the return !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `if` condition is the opposite.
You wrote `if not` but I think it should be `if`.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.template   import RequestContext
from .models import Login

def essai(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':  // here

        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        data = Login(username,password)
        print(data)

        return render(request,'pages/essai.html')
```

Comment: when i also use this instruction i get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your model seems correct. The issue relating to the error message you received is that your view method is checking whether `request` is not `POST`. When sending data from the browser to the server you are "posting" so your view should be listening for `POST`s when accessing data from your HTML form and assigning them to python variables. You also don't actually save your Login object but only just create it in memory. If you call `data.save()` it will trigger a database transaction and attempt to add it to your Login table.

When you initially navigate to the page you trigger a `GET` method as your console output indicates and so you also need to check for `request.GET` in your view method. In your case this should just return a blank HttpResponse via `render()` as you do in your post check. A more complete view function might be:

```python
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
 from django.template import RequestContext
 from .models import Login

def essai(request):

  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    data = Login(username,password)
    print(data)
    data.save() # to save the object to the database if needed.

    return render(request,'pages/essai.html')

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request,'pages/essai.html')
```

The check for `request.GET` might become useful later when you begin needing to modify how your template looks when it loads for the first time.

To display your model object in a more readable manner you can edit your Login model as follows:

from django.db import models

```
class Login(models.Model):
  
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Username: {username} | Password: {password}"
```

Then when you print data it should print a nicely formatted string representation of the data you inputted.

Comment: indeed now it works but after doing this `data.save()`  in the first if I find this kind of error `Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'aaa' `

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to save a string to your model's id field. Or filter by a string rather than integers if you are filtering. Are you working with `Login` from any other page or view? It might also be that you tried to create an `id` field in your model before but haven't unapplied that change via `makemigrations` and `migrate`? if all else fails sometimes its easier to delete your database and start over (if you are in the early testing phases?)

Comment: yes I am in the first phase, I tried to clean my database and redo the magirattion and it shows me the data typed in this form : `ai0S72vVQhs&username=aaaa&password=aaaaa`

Comment: I really don't know why it would print out that way but try make the above edits to your Login model and see if that helps improves the readability when printing and viewing in your admin page.

Comment: But if the answer has been helpful please mark it as accepted.